# Raspbian static IP on Wifi without DCHP service

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface, dhcpcd

I've tried to set up a static IP on a RPi4 running the latest Raspbian Lite (Bullseye), so I can remove DHCP entirely.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I also have `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0`, which looks like:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.133
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4
```

If I run `ip a`, I get the following output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:20:e9:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:20:e9:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.133/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.132/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 6495sec preferred_lft 5595sec
    inet6 fdfc:b729:655a:4bd0:4620:dbb9:867b:fc3d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 1654sec preferred_lft 1654sec
    inet6 fe80::eba1:157a:7b52:9b5c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This looks legit and I can access the Pi on both ...132 and ...133. However, if I disabled dhcpcd.service, I can't access it anymore after a reboot (or if I manually stop dhcpcd.service)

I'm assuming that `ifup` is not called, but I may be completely off. It's a bit difficult to get a keyboard and display on the unit right now, which makes debugging this complicated (since I can't access it if it's not on the network).

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated.

EDIT:

I've started the system with DHCP disabled, left it a minute or two and shut it down, so I can have a look at the logs on a different machine. Seems like the network is going up as expected:

```
Jun 10 12:28:16 rpi-display systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jun 10 12:28:16 rpi-display avahi-daemon[355]: Server startup complete. Host name is rpi-display.local. Local service cookie is 166240168.
Jun 10 12:28:17 rpi-display avahi-daemon[355]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.133.
Jun 10 12:28:17 rpi-display avahi-daemon[355]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 10 12:28:17 rpi-display avahi-daemon[355]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.133 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jun 10 12:28:17 rpi-display systemd[1]: Finished Raise network interfaces.
```

Resolv.conf has the nameservers I configured:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this after I read the last post [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=265229) and realised `dhcpcd` was starting `wpa_supplicant` on `wlan0` through a hook.

After a bit more fiddling around, I realised I need to enable `wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` manually. I copied over the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file to `wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` as it was complaining about missing that, though now that I read @larsks answer, I might have been able to point it to the config file through `interfaces.d/wlan0`.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Using /etc/network/interfaces.d

You need to provide wireless parameters in your `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0` file, either a path to a valid `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.133
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Or you need to provide the SSID and key in the file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.133
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4
  wpa-ssid "MyNetworkName"
  wpa-psk "secretpassword"
```

## Option 2: Using /etc/dhcpcd.conf

Remove your `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0` file.

Edit your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file. You will see the following example configuration:

```
# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1
```

Uncomment that and fill it in with appropriate values:

```
# Example static IP configuration:
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.133/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Re-enable `dhcpcd.service` and reboot.

---

Incidentally, a USB serial cable like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) is tremendously helpful in this sort of situation, because it allows you to plug you Pi into your desktop/laptop and access it via the serial console.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the USB cable. Unfortunately, it's no-go here, because the GPIO is taken up by the display. I guess I could remove it, but it's a bit fragile and I'd want to avoid that.